# How to debug RSuite CMS java plugin?

Tags: mysql, marklogic

I am writing a plugin using RSuite CMS in java.

The problem is every time I do some changes in Java code I have to re-create the Jar file using ANT and then test the plugin. which is very time consuming.

Is there any way to run RSuite it in Debug mode.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is basically no. However, you can debug your code by connecting eclipse to your running tomcat. Also, unless you have a huge plugin, building the jar should not be taking very long. Yes, the process is not ideal (and we are looking into ways to fix that) but it should not be too time consuming.

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Could you please help me in this - "connecting eclipse to your running tomcat"

Comment: There are many ways to connect eclipse to a running tomcat server, but we do know of one way that works reasonably well. First, you need to add "-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8085,server=y,suspend=n" to the JAVA_OPTS of your startup script. In eclipse debug configs, setup a new Remote Java Application, ensuring that the port is the same as the address in the JAVA_OPTS. Once tomcat starts, you can start the debug process in eclipse.